# Median imputation using sapply

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, missing-data

I want to replace missing values in columns of a dataframe. I have written the following code

```
MedianImpute <- function(data=data)
     {
      for(i in 1:ncol(data))
        {        
        if(class(data[,i]) %in% c("numeric","integer"))
          {
          if(sum(is.na(data[,i])))
            {
            data[is.na(data[,i]),i] <- 
                          median(data[,i],na.rm = TRUE)
            }
          }
        }
      return(data)
      }
```

This returns the dataframe with the NAs replaced by the column median.
I do no want to use for loop, how can I get the same result using any of the apply functions in R?

Comment: I think that a `for` loop is a good idea here - It is because some of the columns remain unchanged. BTW, use `is.numeric` in the first if instead of the complex condition in the first `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a subtle problem, so worth a bit of discussion (IMO). You have a `data frame` and want to impute medians for numeric columns only, with the result being, of course, a data frame.

The `apply(...)` function will coerce it's argument to a matrix first. Since all elements in a matrix must by definition be the same data type, *if there are any character or factor columns in the original df, the whole matrix will be coerced to char* when it is passed to `apply(...)`.

```
# 1st column of df is a factor
df <- data.frame(a=letters[1:5],x=sample(1:5,5),y=runif(5))
df[3,]$x <- NA
df[5,]$y <- NA
df
#   a  x         y
# 1 a  5 0.5235779
# 2 b  3 0.2142011
# 3 c NA 0.8886608
# 4 d  4 0.4952574
# 5 e  1        NA

apply(df,2,function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)) ifelse(is.na(x),median(x,na.rm=T),x) else x})
#      a   x    y          
# [1,] "a" " 5" "0.5235779"
# [2,] "b" " 3" "0.2142011"
# [3,] "c" NA   "0.8886608"
# [4,] "d" " 4" "0.4952574"
# [5,] "e" " 1" NA
```

`sapply(df,FUN=f)` will pass the columns of `df` individually to a function `f(...)`, but, *the result will be  matrix*. So, for example, any factors in `df` will be coerced to integer.

```
sapply(df,function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)) ifelse(is.na(x),median(x,na.rm=T),x) else x})
#      a   x         y
# [1,] 1 5.0 0.5235779
# [2,] 2 3.0 0.2142011
# [3,] 3 3.5 0.8886608
# [4,] 4 4.0 0.4952574
# [5,] 5 1.0 0.5094176
```

So here, `df$x` and `df$y` are correct,but look what happened to `df$a`: the factor was coerced to numeric by returning the factor levels - not what you want!

`lapply(df,FUN=F)` will return a list, which can then be converted to a data frame. This approach gives you the desired result:

```
data.frame(lapply(df,function(x) {
    if(is.numeric(x)) ifelse(is.na(x),median(x,na.rm=T),x) else x}))
#   a   x         y
# 1 a 1.0 0.3093707
# 2 b 3.0 0.3486391
# 3 c 3.5 0.8292446
# 4 d 5.0 0.7882574
# 5 e 4.0 0.5684483
```

I suppose it's debatable whether this is any better than using a loop...

Answer (score 5):

You could use `apply` to apply a function across all columns

```
dat<-data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3,NA),c2=c(10, NA, 20, 30))
apply(dat, 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm=T), x))
```

slightly faster

```
imputeMedianv3<-function(x) apply(x, 2, function(x){x[is.na(x)]<-median(x, na.rm=T); x})
```

I'm sure if what you're looking for is performance, someone will provide a data table solution (unfortunately I am not familiar with that package so can't do myself).